# Display and animate a progress bar - by means of CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar

More a question about CSS, than about jQuery.

I display top 7 players and weekly leaders at the bottom of [my Facebook game](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/). The very bottom line displays a random hint in italics font:

[image: top7 and hint]

That **#top** div-block is updated every 10 minutes by the following jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
                $.get("/preftop.html", function(data) {
                        $("#top").html(data);
                });
        }, 10 * 60 * 1000);
});
</script>


<div id="top">
<table width="700" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
......top7.......
</table>
<p>Random hint</p>
</div>
```

It works well, but users aren't given any indication, that the block will be updated again in next 10 minutes.

I've looked at [ajaxload.info](http://www.ajaxload.info/) - those are cool images, but not very suitable here, because the updates aren't happening very often.

So I'd like to display a horizontal bar growing from 0 to 700px every minute (for that I'll change my code to run every 1 * 60 * 1000).

My question is how would you do such a bar? Is there maybe a way to make a yellow bar displayed underneath the random hint line at the bottom of the div?

(And I know there is at least 1 jQuery plugin for displaying a progress bar, but it is not suitable here, because the screen space is limited, it would look too clumsy).

Hoping for good ideas from CSS wizards! Alex

**UPDATE:**

Can't I add **id="hint"** to the <p>Random hint</p> and a yellow bar underneath:

```
#hint {
    background-image:url(yellow.gif);
}
```

and then somehow (that's what missing) increas the width of that yellow rectangle every minute? Is there a width for background images?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have a look at this [Progressbar Plugin](http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php#).

It is very light and easy to use. It also doesn't use that much space.

Edit:
Link added

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use the progress bar built into JQuery?

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar